# Can a wizard use offensive spells and effects from inside a Resilient Sphere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

There are plenty of discussions and chats throughout the internet of how [Resilient Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resilient-sphere) spell works etc.

You can read that:

1. The sphere functions as a wall of force
2. It can be negated by dispel magic
3. Inside the sphere subject can breathe normally
4. The sphere cannot be physically moved either by people outside it or by the struggles of those within
5. Spells cannot pass through a wall of force in either direction, although dimension door, teleport, and similar effects can bypass the barrier
6. Gaze attacks can operate through a wall of force.

One of my players' characters frequently uses Resilient Sphere spell which makes him in game terms a godlike creature. Inside the Sphere he casts Summon Monster spells, uses psionics, etc.  I am just trying to figure out what exactly he can do inside the sphere.

What about offensive mind affecting spells such as [Phantasmal Killer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-killer), [Suggestion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suggestion), [Charm Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person), [Hold Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hold-person), [Lock Gaze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lock-gaze), or sonic spells such as [Wail of the Banshee](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wail-of-the-banshee)?

Is it a question of Line of Effect / Line of Sight rules?

**What types of spells and effects (hex, gaze attacks etc.) can be used by a wizard in offensive way through a Resilient Sphere?**

Answer (score 4):

### Not many.

Since *Resilient Sphere* is essentially a spherical *wall of force*, and *wall of force* breaks line of effect, you cannot cast through it.  Any spells targeting an enemy through the sphere fizzle.

*Summon monster* should not be able to summon anything outside of the sphere.  The caster needs line of effect to the point where the monster will be summoned, and *resilient sphere* prevents this.<sup>1</sup>

Psionics, if they count as spells, also cannot pass through, unless they specifically ignore line of effect (I don't have the occult book so I don't know much about Pathfinder psionics).

Hexes are a gray area.  There is very little information on how they interact with magic, other than them being *supernatural* abilities.  Since they should still follow the general magic rules, I believe they must also have line of effect.

Gaze attacks are specifically called out as working through wall of force, but I don't know of a way to gain a gaze attack off the top of my head.  There are no spells that qualify as gaze attacks, either, as far as I know.

---

<sup>1  This is debatable, but probably how I would rule it.  The question is, is this spell similar at all to teleport or dimension door?  It could be considered either.  On one hand, you are designating a location, just like Dimension Door.  On the other hand, the range is much shorter.  The major difference is, Dimension Door targets *you*, and you are already inside the sphere.</sup>

Comment: What about sonic effects? Like Roar (Su) - Dragonne or Despair (Su) - Mummy etc.

Comment: *Occult Adventures* details “psychic” magic, which could have and should have been called “occult” magic to save everyone a whole lot of headaches. Anyway, psychic magic is magic and spells are cast and they follow pretty much the same rules as arcane and divine magic (different components is the only big difference). It is distinct from “psionics,” which isn’t magic at all, but has the same line-of-effect rules. There is no first-party psionics in Pathfinder; the OGL 3.5e psionics material was ported to Pathfinder and updated, and additional material added on top of it, by Dreamscarred Press.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the [Resilient Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resilient-sphere) spell page:

> The Sphere functions as a wall of force

And the  [Wall of Force](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-force) spell says:

> Breath weapons and spells cannot pass through a wall of force in either direction

Part of what you can do is depending on how you read that second part. Initially I was reading it as no spell can be cast through it, but it could also mean no spell currently in effect can pass through it.

If it's the former, then no directly offensive spells are possible. Lets say though that the caster uses a spell on themselves that grants them a new ability, such as [Fiery Body](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/fieryBody.html) which says:

> Your body burns so brightly that creatures who do not avert their gaze from you are dazzled.

Using this spell on yourself grants a semi-offensive ability towards enemies, though it does depend on their actions. There may be other spells similar to this, but they are most likely very limited in offensive power like this one.

If it's the latter, then there are a lot of options and pretty much everything with a range farther than the sphere can be cast past it.

As it seems Wall of Force and Resilient Sphere are defensive spells I think the first interpretation is more accurate.

Comment: In addition, your answer is wrong.  Wall of Force breaks line of effect; nothing can be cast through it.  A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that indicates what a spell can affect.  A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier.   Wall of force, and thus resilient sphere, create invisible walls of pure force that are solid barriers and thus block line of effect.  See the section on Magic:  http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html

Comment: @LegendaryDude How does that make my answer wrong? I specify both points of view but I also state that I believe nothing can be cast through it

Comment: @zombiemaniac93 Your answer is saying two different things;  I want to vote up the correct part but I don't want to vote up the bad information.

Comment: You are correct, I misread that part of the text. I have updated my answer with I believe a more accurate spell

Answer (score -1):

Get the feat Assume Supernatural Ability...then Polymorph into something with a gaze attack as a supernatural ability, like a Medusa...

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to the Stack. Have you taken the [tour]? Answers here fare better with some elaboration, especially if they can be backed up with experience. Perhaps you could include how/if gaze attacks don't require Line of Effect? Also, please make sure to answer the question first and foremost (Here, it would seem to be "Not usually, but..."). You could provide this information as an edge-case exception that would allow the player to do so.